# c++ source code file encoded using UTF-8 vs UTF-16

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

Why does a C++ source code file compile fine if it's encoded using (`ASCII`,`ISO8859-1` or `UTF-8`), but it doesn't compile if it's encoded using `utf-16` ?

Is the compiler by default assuming that the source code will be encoded in (`ASCII`, `ISO8859-1` or `UTF-8`)? If so, is there any compiler option to change it to recognize other character encodings, like `utf-16` ?

Comment: What compiler (full name and version) are you using?

Comment: For GCC, you can [change the input encoding](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html) with `-finput-charset` or by changing your system locale.

Comment: Here is [some more information](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html#Character-sets) about GCC source file charsets.